# Setting Alerts for Autogrow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

Can I set alerts for an autogrow event in SQL Server (2005 or 2008 R2)?

I've searched around and haven't found the 'error number' for autogrowth, if there is one.

In case this isn't possible, how else do you suggest setting up alerts for autogrow?

I've thought about configuring SQL Server notifications with Service Broker as an alternative, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Event Notifications for `DATA_FILE_AUTO_GROW` and `LOG_FILE_AUTO_GROW` are the appropriate way. Since the autogrowth events are not errors they cannot be detected by the SQL Agent eventing infrastructure so EN is pretty much the only reasonable alternative.